# How to write conversion from Foo<T> to Foo<T const>?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, implicit-conversion

I'm writing a class inheriting from `std::unique_ptr` for classes having a clone function:

```
template <typename T>
class cl_ptr : public std::unique_ptr<T>
{
    public:
        cl_ptr() noexcept = default;
        cl_ptr(T* p) noexcept : std::unique_ptr<T>(p) {}
        cl_ptr(cl_ptr<T> const& cp) : std::unique_ptr<T>(cp ? cp->clone() : nullptr) {}
        cl_ptr(cl_ptr<T>&&) noexcept = default;
        cl_ptr<T>& operator=(cl_ptr<T> const& cp) { this->reset(cp ? cp->clone() : nullptr); return *this; }
        cl_ptr<T>& operator=(cl_ptr<T>&& cp) noexcept = default;
        ~cl_ptr() noexcept = default;
};
```

I have an error when I try to convert from an instance with type `T` to an instance with type `T const`:

```
cl_ptr<Foo> p1(new Foo);
cl_ptr<Foo const> p2 = p1; // <- Compiler error here
// error: conversion from ‘cl_ptr<Foo>’ to non-scalar type ‘cl_ptr<const Foo>’ requested
```

But **I don't know how to implement it**.

Of course I don't want that this code compiles:

```
cl_ptr<Foo const> p1(new Foo);
cl_ptr<Foo> p2 = p1; // <- Always wrong
```

Minimal reproductible example:

```
# include <memory>

template <typename T>
class cl_ptr : public std::unique_ptr<T>
{
    public:
        cl_ptr() noexcept = default;
        cl_ptr(T* p) noexcept : std::unique_ptr<T>(p) {}
        cl_ptr(cl_ptr<T> const& cp) : std::unique_ptr<T>(cp ? cp->clone() : nullptr) {}
        cl_ptr(cl_ptr<T>&&) noexcept = default;
        cl_ptr<T>& operator=(cl_ptr<T> const& cp) { this->reset(cp ? cp->clone() : nullptr); return *this; }
        cl_ptr<T>& operator=(cl_ptr<T>&& cp) noexcept = default;
        ~cl_ptr() noexcept = default;
};

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo() = default;
        Foo(Foo const&) = default;
        ~Foo() noexcept = default;
        Foo* clone() const { return new Foo(*this); }
};

int main()
{
    cl_ptr<Foo> p1(new Foo);
    cl_ptr<Foo const> p2 = p1;
    cl_ptr<Foo> p3 = p2; // must fail

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where are all the `#include`s? What is `Foo`? Where/how is it defined.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr`, like most standard classes, is not made for being inherited from.

Comment: "I'm writing a class inheriting from std::unique_ptr" WHY? What is a rationale? This is strange requirement. Basically this looks like [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @molbdnilo: I know. It's not my question.

Comment: @MarekR: you can imagine I'm writing my own version of smart pointer from scratch and ask the same question.

Comment: Your issue, unless I overlooked the question, is not related to `std::unique_ptr` nor even to the clone function. You could have reduced your minimal example to basically an empty template class and see that `A<int>` and  `A<const int>` are two unrelated types (hence why the implicit conversion does not work).

Comment: @Caduchon That's why it's not an answer, but an encouragement to stop doing that immediately.

Comment: @Fareanor: right. But I expect exaclty the same behaviour than the conversion from `std::unique_ptr<T>` to `std::unique_ptr<T const>`. Then I let the context.

Comment: @Caduchon It doesn't work [with `std::unique_ptr` neither](https://godbolt.org/z/5x8dWEn3o).

Comment: @Fareanor: I thought shared_ptr

Comment: Why do you "of course" want the cloning of a const object to fail? It seems very counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Fareanor - of course it didn't work, you didn't move it. Once you do, the conversion is not a problem.

Comment: @molbdnilo: because `*p1` is a non-const access.

Comment: @Caduchon You can absolutely dereference a pointer-to-const.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<T>` in particular has a templated constructor (overload (6) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr)) accepting an rvalue of type `std::unique_ptr<U>` for any type `U` where `U*` is convertible to `T*`. It so happens that `Foo*` is convertible to `Foo const*`, so this templated constructor works for this conversion. If you want your class to behave like `std::unique_ptr`, add a similar constructor.

Comment: I'd make the conversion explicit, with `auto to_const() const -> cl_ptr<T const> { return cl_ptr<T const>{p ? p->clone() : nullptr}; }` and if desired `auto to_mutable() const -> cl_ptr<std::remove_const_t<T>> { return cl_ptr<std::remove_const_t<T>>{p ? p->clone() : nullptr}; }`.  (I'm **cloning** here, but you could change underlying ownership.  Changing ownership for the `to_mutable` case is (probably) a really bad idea.)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Oh right, `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable, what a scatterbrained hasty writer I make :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to allow any conversion of `cl_ptr<T>` to `cl_ptr<U>` where there is a conversion from `T *` to `U *`, just like `std::unique_ptr`. This allows `T *` to `const T *` and doesn't allow `const T *` to `T *`, but also includes `Derived *` to `Base *` etc.

```
template <typename T>
class cl_ptr : public std::unique_ptr<T>
{
    public:
        cl_ptr() noexcept = default;
        cl_ptr(T* p) noexcept : std::unique_ptr<T>(p) {}
        cl_ptr(cl_ptr<T> const& cp) : std::unique_ptr<T>(cp ? cp->clone() : nullptr) {}
        cl_ptr(cl_ptr<T>&&) noexcept = default;
        cl_ptr<T>& operator=(cl_ptr<T> const& cp) { this->reset(cp ? cp->clone() : nullptr); return *this; }
        cl_ptr<T>& operator=(cl_ptr<T>&& cp) noexcept = default;

        template <typename U, typename  = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U*, T*>>>
        cl_ptr(cl_ptr<U> const& cp) : std::unique_ptr<T>(cp ? cp->clone() : nullptr) {}
        template <typename U, typename  = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U*, T*>>>
        cl_ptr(cl_ptr<U>&& cp) noexcept : std::unique_ptr<T>(std::move(cp)) {}
        template <typename U, typename  = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U*, T*>>>
        cl_ptr<T>& operator=(cl_ptr<U> const& cp) { this->reset(cp ? cp->clone() : nullptr); return *this; }
        template <typename U, typename  = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U*, T*>>>
        cl_ptr<T>& operator=(cl_ptr<T>&& cp) noexcept { this->reset(cp.release()); return *this; }

        ~cl_ptr() noexcept = default;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In general: You cannot. `A<B const>` and `A<B>` could be *entirely* different things because of template specialisation. So in general class template instances with different template argument lists are treated as distinct, unrelated types.

In the case of smart pointers the standard library goes to great lengths to enable such conversions under certain circumstances but these are all custom implementations for the respective class template.

You *could* do the same for your specific class. But `cl_ptr` seems like a trivial wrapper for `std::unique_ptr` so why not use `std::unique_ptr` directly?

Comment: I use a lot of containers of std::unique_ptr of clonable objects. It make impossible to let the compiler write the copy construtor and assignment operator in classes having such a container.